# Dryer plug won’t seat

Tags: dryer

Just tried to plug in my dryer. Both the receptacle and the plug look compatible, but the receptacle won’t take the dryer plug in fully. Took a picture of the receptacle, looks like the vertical slot on the left side has something blocking the way. Not sure if I should just push harder or something else is the problem.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Does look like something is in there, that is not suppose to be.

Before sticking anything in there turn off the breaker.  You do not wants an oops with 240 volts. It hurts bad.

If that piece does not pull out easy, might need to take apart the outlet or replace it.

Comment: If all it does is hurts bad, you're lucky.

Comment: did the old plug come out OK?  Any missing prongs?   I vote for replacement, ...and a new cord.  Hopefully the OP will have the skills and tools to do that.

Comment: A new replacement does not cost much and won't have to worry if anything else is wrong with it.